# Remix compiler is not loading and gives "Compiler not yet loaded." message when attempting to force

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, compiler, browsers

This issue is occurring on both chrome and firefox. I have not changed anything from a week ago when it worked fine. The remix compiler works on Edge browser but not the other 2.

If anyone has any reason for this or fix, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your adblock. I think that's the issue. I also had the same problem today in Chrome, but when I tried it in Firefox (where I don't use adblocks) it works.

Comment: I'm getting this issue in Remix via Mist, so there's no adblock here.